# What is contained in Androids Bugreport?

Tags: android, adb

I have been searching all around the Internet to find out what is contained in the android bugreport.
I am referring to the one you can generate by executing

```
adb bugreport
```

I am curious if the created .zip would contain Device crashes, Fatal exceptions and similar.
Where would they be found if yes?
Is there any documentation on what is and where archived?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Android Bugreport contains debug information like contents of the logcat buffers (main, radio, system, events, crash), dump of all the packages installed, ANR stack traces, network, data usage, battery usage, wakelocks etc. After extracting the zip file, you will see a text file with "bugreport" or "dumpstate" prefix which contains the logs from logcat buffers. The most recent exceptions and crashes can be found in that file.

For example search for string `"beginning of crash"` to find the crashes. `"beginning of main"`  in the file is the start of logcat main buffer logs.

See Android documentation for more details https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/read-bug-reports